# Smoothness of $A \subseteq C$ implies smoothness of $B \subseteq C$? where $A\subseteq B \subseteq C$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ be commutative rings (noetherian integral domains, if this helps).
Assume $C$ is a smooth $A$-algebra. Is it true that $C$ is a smooth $B$-algebra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No!
Take  $A=k$, a field, $C=k[T]$, which is a smooth $k$-algebra, and $B=k[T^2,T^3]\subset C$.
Then $C$ is not smooth over $B$ because it is not flat over $B$.

**Edit**
It is easy to soup up the preceding example to the case ( which the  OP is interested in according to his comment below) where $A$ is no longer a field.
Just take $A'=k[S], C'=k[S,T]$ and $B'=k[S,T^2,T^3]$.

Comment: Thank you both! In your counterexamples $A$ is a field. In the cse I had in mind $A$ is not a field. But I guess one can still find a counterexample in which $A$ is not a field.

Comment: @user237522 I think you can do exactly the same but with $\Bbb{Z}$ replaced with $k$.

Comment: Yes, I have provided such an example in an edit.

Comment: ...and @Ben Lim's suggestion is an excellent alternative.

Comment: Thanks for Georges Elencwajg for his counterexample with $A=K[x]$, and thanks for Ben Lim for his counterexample with $A=\mathbb{Z}$! I guess there exists a counterexample with $A=K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $C=K[x_1,\ldots.x_n,x_{n+1}]$, similar to the $n=1$ case?

Comment: Dear user: yes!

Comment: Dear  @Ben Lim: thanks for your kind words. None of my maps are étale and I don't know how to modify them in order to get a counter-example in the étale case. Which certainly does not mean that you or some other competent user could not  easily find such a modification ...

Comment: It would be a bit harder to get a counterexample for the étale case: given morphisms $f : X \to Y$ and $g : Y \to Z$ (of schemes), assuming $g : Y \to Z$ is étale, $g \circ f : X \to Z$ is étale if and only if $f : X \to Y$ is étale. So any counterexample would need to have $g : Y \to Z$ not étale.

Answer (score 2):

No. Let $k$ be a field and let $n$ be a positive integer such that $n \ne 0$ in $k$. Consider $k \subseteq k [x^n] \subseteq k [x]$. Then $k [x]$ and $k [x^n]$ are both smooth $k$-algebras (of dimension $1$), but $k [x]$ is not a smooth $k [x^n]$-algebra: if it were, then it would be étale, but it has a non-reduced fibre.