# Smoothness of a subalgebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, flatness

Assume $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ are commutative noetherian domains of zero characteristic, $C$ is a f.g. $B$-module, $B$ is a f.p. $A$-algebra ($B$ is not necessarily a f.g. $A$-module), $C$ is a flat and separable $A$-algebra (hence, $C$ is a smooth $A$-algebra) and $B$ is a flat $A$-algebra.

**My question:** Is it true that $B$ is a smooth $A$-algebra?; equivalently, is it true that $fd_{B \otimes_A B}(B) < \infty$? (please see [Corollary 2](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02566621#page-1)).

- I have tried to show formal smoothness of $B$ over $A$ (since $B$ is f.p. over $A$, smoothness is equivalent to formal smoothness), namely: For each $A$-algebra $E$, and each ideal $J$ in $E$ with $J^2=0$, the canonical homomorphism $Hom_{A−alg}(B,E) \to Hom_{A−alg}(B,E/J)$ is surjective. However, I had a problem when, given an $A$-algebras homomorphism $f: B \to E/J$ to extend it to an $A$-algebras homomorphism $F: C \to E/J$ (since, if we have such $F$, then $F$ has a preimage $G: C \to E$, and then we can restrict $G$ to $B$, and get a preimage for $f$, if I am not wrong).
- I suspect there exists a counterexample.

**Remarks:**
(1) [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392686/a-subseteq-b-subseteq-c-with-a-subseteq-c-separable-and-pd-b-otimes-a) is not applicable in the current question, since there $B$ is not a domain. (Also, I prefer to assume that $A$ is not a field, and here $C$ is not assumed to be a finitely generated $A$-module).
(2) [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317154/smoothness-of-a-subseteq-c-implies-smoothness-of-b-subseteq-c-where-a-su) asks about smoothness of $C$ over $B$.
(3) Please see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217890/smoothness-of-a-subalgebra-of-a-smooth-algebra).

Comment: What if $A = k$, a field, $\operatorname{Spec}(B)$ a nodal curve in $\mathbf{A}^2_k$ and $\operatorname{Spec}(C)$ the normalization of $B$ in $K(B)$?

Comment: Can you take $A=\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $A=k$?

Comment: It is no problem to use $A=k[a]$, so one can take a curve as base instead of a point. In the case $A=\mathbb{Z}$ computing an integral closure gets more complicated (Macaulay 2 can not do it), so I don't know at the moment if one could take $A=\mathbb{Z}$ without modifying the example.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the probably trivial question, but can we take $A=k[a,b]$? Are all the conditions satisfied? (separability, flatness etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me come back to my initial example $A = k$, $B=k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$, $C$ the integral closure of $B$ in its quotient field $K(B)$.

Then $B/A$ is flat and of finite type, $C$ is nonsingular, therefore $C/k$ smooth, and $C/B$ is finite. The properties "finite", "of finite type", "flat" and "smooth" are preserved under base extension. Therefore it is possible to extend the base $A=k$ to every $k$--scheme $S$. Of course this gives only utterly trivial examples, as every fiber is the same.

To get something a little more interesting one can use the slightly changed original setup:

$$
\begin{align}
A & =\mathbb{Q}[a,b] \\
B & =A[x,y]/((y-b)^2-((x-a)^3+(x-a)^2))
\end{align}
$$

and $C$ again the integral closure of $B$ in its quotient field.

If one computes $\Omega_{C|A}$ one gets $C$, so it is free of rank $1$ as necessary for smoothness over $A$.

The computation of $\Omega_{C|A}$ goes over the sequence

$$(*) \quad I/I^2 \to \Omega_{S|A} \otimes_S C \to \Omega_{C|A} \to 0$$

where $C = S/I$ and $S=A[w,x,y]$, $I=(f_1,f_2,f_3) \subseteq S$ a certain ideal of three elements of $S$ that is found by Macaulay 2 on computing the integral closure $C$ of $B$.

It remains to prove flatness of $C$ and $B$ over $A$. Flatness of $B$ over $A$ follows from the following statement:

Let $R[X_1,\ldots,X_n] = S$ and $S_1=S/(f)$, $f \in S$. Then $S_1$ is flat over $R$ if for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $R$ the ring $S_1 \otimes_R R/\mathfrak{m}$ is not equal to $S \otimes_R R/\mathfrak{m}$.

This can be found in Milne, Etale Cohomology, Chapter 1, Remark 2.6(a).

To prove the flatness of $C = S/I$ over $A$ seems to be more difficult and I currently can not prove it. The case $A=k[a]$ is considerably simpler in this regard, as one needs only check that every irreducible component of the domain dominates $\operatorname{spec}(A)$.

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you very much! Please, (1) Is there a special reason why you have taken $A= \mathbb{Q}[a,b]$ and not, for example, $A= \mathbb{C}[a,b]$ (or $A= \mathbb{Z}[a,b]$)? (2) What if $B=A[T]/(g)$ instead of $B=A[T_1,T_2]/(g)$?

Comment: I took $A=\mathbb{Q}[a,b]$ so I could compute with Macaulay 2, as all appearing algebras are of finite type over $\mathbb{Q}$. For finite type algebras over $\mathbb{Z}$ many algorithms of Macaulay 2 don't work.

Comment: Thank you again. If anyone can prove flatness of $C$ over $A$ that would be nice; maybe this should be posted (by you or me or someone else) as a new question (probably you will find a proof, so you will not bother to post this as a question).