# Can the following theorem about flatness be generalized?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $R$ be a commutative noetherian domain, $S=R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $S_1=S/(f)$ , $f\in S$. Then $S_1$ is flat over $R$ if for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ in $R$  the ring $S_1 \otimes_R R/\mathfrak m$ is not equal to $S \otimes_R R/\mathfrak m$.

This can be found in Milne, Etale Cohomology, Chapter 1, Remark 2.6(a); I have seen this nice result thanks to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1430054/121097).

My question:

> Can this theorem be somehow generalized to the case where $S_1=S/(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$, $f_1,\ldots,f_m \in S$? Is it easier to answer for $n=1$ or $n=2$?

(Maybe if $n > m$ there is an answer; maybe in this case $S_1$ is never flat over $R$.)

Comment: If you notice that for a single $f$ what you are actually using (follows from your hypothesis) is that $f$ is a non-zero divisor in $S$ and remains one modulo any maximal ideal of $R$. So, the correct generalization is, that if you have $f_1,\ldots, f_m$, which form a regular sequence in $S$ and remains a regular sequence modulo any maximal ideal of $R$, you will get flatness. At least, this is one possible generalization.